# X-FORWARDED-HOST Multiple Parameters Accepted?

Tags: rest, http, soap, http-headers, x-forwarded-for

I am working on a SOAP Web Service Issue. However I have a ambiguity if X-Forwarded-Host accepts multiple values like `X-FORWARDED-HOST: www.example.com, www.example1.com`
I've read the Apache documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers where it points this headers can have comma separated values in the note there.
There is still some ambiguity for me, since when I try with multiple values I get a HTTP 500 error response code.

And what about Reverse-Proxy Cascade Scenarios?